# What are the ways to flush a Linux command's stdout as a Node.js child process?

Tags: node.js

What are the ways to flush a Linux command's stdout as a Node.js child process?

Ending the stdin stream (`child.stdin.end`) will work. As will unbuffering the command with `stdbuf`.

But I imagine there's a proper way to stream results from external commands.

How do we tell a command we're ready to consume while we are still providing data?

Example:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('uniq');
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stdin.write('a\nb\nb\nc\n', 'utf8');
// No output, child is still running.
```

(`uniq` is just an example here. It's the same with most Linux commands.)

Comment: In general, no, but in the case of GNU grep, it also can take the `--line-buffered` argument, forcing its stdout to be line buffered.

Comment: Yes, I knew about `--line-buffered`, I should have picked a more general example. I'm changing it to `wc`.

I really don't understand why Unix was engineered that way. In Node, for example, there is a mechanism to allow process to regulate backpressure between them (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/ is a very good read, btw). Why is such an important feature absent from Linux? (apart from using workarounds such as stdbuf).

Comment: Why is `child.stdin.end()` less than ideal? `wc -l` can't give you output until it has consumed the entire stream anyway.

Comment: @Paulpro, `wc` was just an example. Most Linux command behave the same way as for the buffering.

Comment: Most commands are written in C, and C programs buffer stdout in a particular way. The output is either line buffered, unbuffered or fully buffered. By default such an output is line buffered if the output is a terminal (for interactive use) or fully buffered (often a buffer of 4096 bytes is used otherwise). What you're seeing is a fully buffered stream, that isn't yet full, so you don't get any output(yet). Use the commands own flags to control that, if no such flag exists, use stdbuf. There's rarely a drawback to using unbuffered output if the output is small. Or just set it to line buffered.

Comment: Thank you @nos. I would select your comment as the answer if I could.